# Delete Current Row in Php

Tags: php, mysql

How can i delete the current row from Mysql using php ?

I want to search from my Mysql database, every individual row has a Delete button on right side.
When i click on Delete button, that current row should be deleted from database.
I've tried to create a function in php that contains the Query to delete from database. But its not working when i call it in my Search block.

I've created two functions, one in PHP (named as "hello") that contains the Delete Query and one in JavaScript (named as "DeleteRecord") that is calling php function "hello".
Now i called JS function in my Search block.
JS function is working fine, but when JS call a php function, it also works if i just use echo, but within php function if i un comment the Delete Query, it doesn't work !

Anyone to help me out 
Thanks !

```
function viewRecord($Para)
{

echo "<table border=1>
     <thead>
     <th>Book_Number</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Auther</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Shelf</th>
     </thead>";

     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($Para))
     {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Book_Number']."</td>";          
          global $DeleteRecordNumber;
          $DeleteRecordNumber = $row['Book_Number']; 
          echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Auther']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Quantity']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Shelf']."</td>";          
          echo "<td>"."<input type=button value=Delete onclick=DeleteRecord()>"."</td>"; 
          echo "</tr>";      
     }
     echo "</table>";         
}

function hello()
          {
               global $DeleteRecordNumber;
               $asd = $DeleteRecordNumber;
               echo  $asd;                          
    // $Del = "DELETE FROM books WHERE Book_Number='$asd'";
   //  mysql_query($Del); 
          }

mysql_close($Connection);

?>

<script type=text/javascript>
function DeleteRecord()
{       
     document.write (<?php hello(); ?>);
}
</script>
```

Comment: and the `DELETE from...` is? or is that irrelevant?

Comment: 'Book_Number' is the unique ID of an individual row.
I'm using that unique number to delete the specific row.

Comment: In your DeleteRecord() you need to insert the primary key for the record i.e. onclick=DeleteRecord('"+pk + "'). In the javascript function - pass this value to php. In php, set the necessary sql statement.

Comment: I've done that.
Now i've briefly explained the problem with all solutions that i tried.
Please review !

Comment: Don't DELETE stuff. Just have a 'hidden' or 'deleted' flag that can be UPDATED to 1 when 'Delete' is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a minute, i think you are mixing apples with oranges! You cannot execute a PHP function on the client side using a button unless you submit the form. The more i look at your post the more errors i Find.

However, assuming you ARE submitting the command (you are not showing what DeleteRecord() does, so i will assume you have a form submision there), You should have a unique field in your table, for example 'id" which would be of type NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY.

When dislpaying your rows, have each row to hold this unique id. Then when the button is pressed simply do:

```
$result = MySQL_Query("DELETE QUICK FROM books WHERE id='idtodelete'");
```

Update the query with your table name and a unique id, That should do it.
converting it to function should go like:

```
function delete_record($id)
 {
   return MySQL_Query("DELETE QUICK FROM books WHERE id=$id");
 }
```

If you dont want to use a unique field, use anything that is unique, like an email or something that is not present in another record in the same table, like your field 'Book_Number', but it is more standard the field 'id'.

Column names are case-sensitive, so, if your query is not working as it should, check the character case of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to delete a record without refreshing the page?

If so you can remove the element via javascript/jquery and on the delete function you would make an ajax post call to the server with the book id and the operation to perform.

In [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) it would look like (assuming you put an id in your book_number`<td>` as book_number):

```
<script>
var data = {
    book_id: $("#book_number"),
    operation:"delete"
}
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", data, function() {
  alert( "Record deleted" );
  //delete the row from the table
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "Alternative to the above" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error deleting record" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "Operation completed" );
});
</script>
```

On the php side, in example.php you would need to adapt your code to include some processing if the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is equal to `"POST"` and if so, in your query string you would place:

```
"DELETE FROM books WHERE Book_Number='{$_POST['book_id']}'";
```

Keep in mind that although this might work, it is not safe from SQL injection, you would need to use [some form of escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to safeguard your queries from SQL Injection.

---

Another way to do it would be to have the delete button serve as a submit button for a form with the book_number being passed around and do the same above but this time around without the Javascript part. This would force a page reload.